# Bazel: how to import/build a go_binary for a go_test

Tags: go, bazel

I'm using bazel to run a go test on my CI system. The go test will need to use a helper binary built from another go file.

The dir structure looks like the following:

```
    some/of/my/path
    ├── BUILD.bazel
    ├── my_utils.go
    ├── my_test.go
    └── my_tool
        ├── BUILD.bazel
        └── my_tool.go
```

**I.e. the code in `my_test.go` is going to use the executable binary built from dir `my_tool`.**

In a non-bazel case, I can just `go build ./mytool` to get the executable binary that `my_test.go` needs. To accommodate this the bazel world, I write the following in the bazel files:

- In `some/of/my/path/BUILD.bazel`:

```
    load("@io_bazel_rules_go//go:def.bzl", "go_library", "go_test")
    
    go_library(
        name = "testutils",
        srcs = ["my_utils.go"],
        importpath = "some/of/my/path",
        visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
        deps = [
            "@org_golang_x_net//context",
            ... (some other dependencies, not related)
        ],
    )
    
    go_test(
        name = "my_test",
        size = "enormous",
        srcs = ["mytest.go"],
        embed = [":testutils"],
        deps = [
            "//some/of/my/path/my_tool:my_tool",
        ],
    )
```

- In `some/of/my/path/my_tool/BUILD.bazel`

```
    load("@io_bazel_rules_go//go:def.bzl", "go_binary", "go_library")
    
    go_library(
        name = "my_tool_lib",
        srcs = ["my_tool.go"],
        importpath = "some/of/my/path/my_tool",
        visibility = ["//visibility:private"],
        deps = ["some dependency"],
    )
    
    go_binary(
        name = "my_tool",
        embed = [":my_tool_lib"],
        visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    )
```

So the idea is when I hit `bazel run`, it will build the `my_tool` go binary, which the go test `my_test` can use (see the `deps` field of the go test).

While in the CI I hit this error:

```
    ERROR: /home/agent/work/.go/src/some/of/my/path/BUILD.bazel:20:8: in go_test rule //some/of/my/path:my_test:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/agent/.cache/bazel/_bazel_agent/40f5e2a2e18a7cdb4cd075f919d8072b/external/io_bazel_rules_go/go/private/rules/test.bzl", line 66, column 43, in _go_test_impl
        internal_source = go.library_to_source(go, ctx.attr, internal_library, ctx.coverage_instrumented())
      File "/home/agent/.cache/bazel/_bazel_agent/40f5e2a2e18a7cdb4cd075f919d8072b/external/io_bazel_rules_go/go/private/context.bzl", line 247, column 26, in _library_to_source
        _check_binary_dep(go, dep, "deps")
      File "/home/agent/.cache/bazel/_bazel_agent/40f5e2a2e18a7cdb4cd075f919d8072b/external/io_bazel_rules_go/go/private/context.bzl", line 295, column 13, in _check_binary_dep
        fail("rule {rule} depends on executable {dep} via {edge}. This is not safe for cross-compilation. Depend on go_library instead.".format(
    Error in fail: rule //some/of/my/path:my_test depends on executable //some/of/my/path/my_tool:my_tool via deps. This is not safe for cross-compilation. Depend on go_library instead.
    ERROR: Analysis of target '//some/of/my/path:my_test' failed; build aborted: Analysis of target '//some/of/my/path:my_test' failed
    INFO: Elapsed time: 79.552s
    INFO: 0 processes.
    FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (595 packages loaded, 12182 targets configured)
    ERROR: Build failed. Not running target
    FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (595 packages loaded, 12182 targets configured)
    Process exited with code 1
```

But my goal is to use the binary. How should I change the configs to achieve that?

Comment: If you use the `my_tool` program only as a binary called in a subprocess, add it to the `data` deps instead.

Comment: @Laurenz I'm a bit confused about "use the my_tool program only as a binary called in a subprocess", could you explain more? (putting it in an answer would be awesome!) thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `data`, not `deps`. `deps` is for things linked into a binary, `data` is for things the binary uses at runtime.

Once your binary is in `data`, use [runfiles.go](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/blob/master/go/tools/bazel/runfiles.go) to run it. Add `@io_bazel_rules_go//go/tools/bazel:go_default_library` to `deps` (it's a library you want linked in), and then use `FindBinary` to find the path.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! Could you elaborate more on how to use `bazel.FindBinary`? I noticed the first argument of this function is a package. Does it mean the package of my current go file, or a package name in bazel?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with the Go rules to answer that. Hopefully your separate question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71120426 for anybody from the future) finds somebody who can.