# Bazel: how to get the path of a binary that I built along a bazel test

Tags: go, bazel

I'm writing a go test with bazel. The test will build a binary first, and mount the binary to a docker container. So I need to know the path of the binary I built.

The file system structure is like this:

The dir structure looks like the following:

```
    some/of/my/path
    ├── BUILD.bazel
    ├── my_test.go
    └── my_tool
        ├── BUILD.bazel
        └── my_tool.go
```

where I'd like to build a go binary with go files at `my_tool` dir.

From [my previous question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70839839/10400141), I got to know that I can use the `data` entry of in `go_test` from  `some/of/my/path/BUILD.bazel` to build the binary:

```
go_test(
    name = "my_test",
    srcs = ["my_test.go"],
    data = glob(["testdata/**"]) + [
        "//some/of/my/path/my_tool:my_tool",
    ],
    gotags = ["my_test"],
    deps = [
        "//pkg/util/contextutil",
        "//pkg/util/log",
    ...
    ],
)
```

which did build the go binary for `my_tool`. But now the question is, how do I know **where** is the built binary of `my_tool` in `my_test.go`?

In `my_test.go`, I need to write something like this:

```
package my_lucky_test

...

pathForMyTool := some_path
hostConfig := container.HostConfig{
Binds := []string {""%s/my_tool-bin:/workding-dir/my_tool-bin", pathForMyTool"}
}
```

My question is how can I get the absolute path of "my_tool-bin"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply run;

```
bazel build //some/of/my/path:my_test
```

It should print out the path of the binary to stdout.

As an alternative to your current approach might I suggest that you make use of [bazelbuild/rules_docker#go_image](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker#go_image) which is a Bazel aware method for building containers.

EDIT: OP has clarified the question, though I am leaving the original answer above as others may find it useful.

When you bundle a binary/test with some data, the files under the data attribute become a set of 'runfiles'. There are various libraries in each language for resolving runfiles. For golang you'll want to use the [bazel pkg](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/go/tools/bazel) in rules_go, to resolve your runfiles. e.g.

```py
go_test(
    name = "my_test",
    srcs = ["my_test.go"],
    data = glob(["testdata/**"]) + [
        "//some/of/my/path/my_tool:my_tool",
    ],
    gotags = ["my_test"],
    deps = [
        "//pkg/util/contextutil",
        "//pkg/util/log",
        # NEW dep
        "@rules_go//rules_go/go/tools/bazel",
    ...
    ],
)
```

Your `my_test.go`;

```golang
package my_lucky_test

# NEW
import(
    "github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/go/tools/bazel"
)

#...

pathForMyTool, ok := bazel.FindBinary("some/of/my/path/my_tool", "my_tool")
if !ok {
    # Error handling
}
hostConfig := container.HostConfig{
    Binds := []string {""%s/my_tool-bin:/workding-dir/my_tool-bin", pathForMyTool}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Sorry I wasn't being clear -- I'm looking for the path of `my_tool` binary, not `my_test`. `my_tool` binary is expected to be built along with the `my_test`, since I added `"//some/of/my/path/my_tool:my_tool",` to the `data` field of the go_test.

Comment: Ah righto, no worries I've updated my answer